# Why am I getting "None" after merging two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have the following Python script where I merge two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'bookA': 1, 'bookB': 2, 'bookC': 3}
dict2 = {'bookC': 2, 'bookD': 4, 'bookE': 5}
print dict2.update(dict1)
```

Why do I get as output `None` rather than the merged dictionaries? How can I display the result?

Thanks.

Comment: Because `dict.update()` works in-place and doesn't return a new dictionary object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update does not return a new dictionary. 
Do this instead:

```
dict1 = {'bookA': 1, 'bookB': 2, 'bookC': 3}
dict2 = {'bookC': 2, 'bookD': 4, 'bookE': 5}
dict2.update(dict1)
print(dict2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict2.update(dict1)` updates `dict2`, but doesn't return it. Use `print dict2` instead.